# Cast between types using only protocols?

Tags: swift, casting, protocols

I have 2 `structs` that are only related by protocols. I'm trying to cast between the two types since they share a protocol, but I get a runtime error.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
protocol A {
    var id: String { get }
    var name: String { get }
    var isActive: Bool { get set }
}

struct Entity: A {
    let id: String
    var name: String
    var isActive: Bool

    func someFun() {
        print("\(name), active: \(isActive)")
    }
}

struct ViewModel: A {
    let id: String
    var name: String
    var isActive: Bool
}

let vm = ViewModel(id: "abc", name: "John Doe", isActive: true)
let pt = vm as A
let et = pt as! Entity
print(et.someFun()) //crash
```

The error I get is:

```
Could not cast value of type '__lldb_expr_87.ViewModel' (0x111835638) to '__lldb_expr_87.Entity' (0x111835550).
```

This is a real bummer because if I have millions of records, I don't want to have to loop through each one to manually convert one by one. I was hoping to implicitly cast magically like this:

```
let entity = vm as A as Entity
let entities = vms as [A] as [Entity]
```

Any performance-conscious way to pass objects between boundaries without looping through each one?

Comment: You can't do that because the protocol guarantees only that both types have implemented the protocol requirements. It does not guarantee that both types are interchangeable. By the way Swift provides functions like `map` to avoid loops (the framework uses a loop under the hood though).

Answer (score 0):

As vadian stated in his comment, you can't typecast like this. To perform what you are trying to do by typecasting, you would need to do something like this:

```
let entity = Entity(id: vm.id, name: vm.name, isActive: vm.isActive)

let entities = vms.map {
  return Entity(id: $0.id, name: $0.name, isActive: $0.isActive
}
```

The reason why you are crashing is because typecasting doesn't change the properties and methods that an object actually *has*, only the methods and properties they have access *to*. If you performed the following, you would lose access to your someFun() method:

```
let entityAsA = Entity(id: "id", name: "name", isActive: true) as A
```

However, the following will compile and run without crashing:

```
(entityAsA as! Entity).someFun()
```

So, when you attempt to cast from ViewModel to A to Entity, it doesn't change the way the value was created in memory (without access to a function called someFun() ) and you'll crash every time.